# GEE Interpretation beta coefficient

Tags: interpretation, regression-coefficients, gamma-distribution, generalized-estimating-equations

I am running a Generalized Estimating Equation in STATA with link(log) corr(independent) family(gamma) and vce(robust).
The results of the command...

```
xtgee dependentvariable independentvariable controlvariables, link(log) corr(independent) iterate(100) family(gamma) vce(robust)
```

...provides me with a negative value for the beta coefficient

According to Ballinger (2004) "The regression coefficients that result from GEE models for
logit, probit, and log links need to be exponentiated before they are meaningful."
I am using a log link. If I get this the right way then the -eform- (according to the STATA help displays  the  exponentiated  coefficients  and  corresponding  standard  errors  and  confidence intervals) option should be used for this.

So I am running:

```
xtgee dependentvariable independentvariable controls, link(log) corr(independent) iterate(100) family(gamma) vce(robust) eform
```

But now the value for the beta coefficient turns out to be positive. Is it correct to only interpret the positive beta coefficient after adding -eform-?

Would be really great to get help on this question.

Comment: If you exponentiate a negative number you get a positive number.

Comment: @mdewey Thank you for your comment. Yes exactly. But my question is if this is really the right procedure in this case.

Comment: So if my hypothesis is that my independent variable (x) has a positive effect on my dependent variable (Y) and not on the ln(y) 

Would I support the hypothesis?

Comment: I do not understand how you can affect Y without affecting ln(Y) or vice versa.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. The question is just if I should interpret the first negative coefficient for my hypothesis or the second one which is positive 
Hypothesis: x has a positive effect on y